# git merge branches bitbucket doesnt show merge

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

Having a minor issue with git/bitbucket.

Working on a small project and for each feature I create a branch, implement the feature, push that branch to bitbucket. At this point, bitbucket shows my commits in the branch. I merge the branch into the master. Then push the master to bitbucket, however once I do this, bitbucket no longer shows any commits under the branch, and doesnt show any type of branches in the commits page of master either - wheras for other merges (not sure which ones) I get a double line showing where each commit was made to a different branch, and the commit which merged them. Why do I not see this now?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely the difference between fast-forward and non-fast-forward merges. If only one branch has advanced, the other branch can be "fast-forwarded" and there is no merge commit.

See [Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) specifically:

> ... when you try to merge one commit with a commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward because there is no divergent work to merge together — this is called a "fast forward".

Comment: I see, so in this case there is no difference to me just committing changes to the master branch? So if I know no-one else is going to be making a change, this is acceptable?